# Merging two std::variant

Tags: c++, variant

Is it possible to merge `std::variant`s?
Maybe something similar as shown by the following example code is possible?

```
#include <variant>

using Var1 = std::variant<int, bool>;
using Var2 = std::variant<float, double>;

// both lines should yield the same
using MergedVariant = std::merge<Var1, Var2>; // <-- how to do this?
using MergedVariant = std::variant<int, bool, float, double>; // expected
```

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/T37KE81nf